# Unexpected DUP ACK

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark

I'm developing HTTP server with C#/.NET using sockets and on one of test machines get strange duplicate ACKs when test it with Wireshark. It happens on one machine only, when I test on other ones I get no such DUP ACKs.

In the dump below DUP ACK is #32 . Both browser and server on same test machine. Sequence and acknowledge numbers seems completely correct in the dump below, so I wondered why it may happens?

```
"No.","Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Length","Info"
"18","2.963325","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","52","49652 > 10000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1"
"19","2.963325","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","52","10000 > 49652 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1"
"20","2.963325","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","40","49652 > 10000 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=0"
"25","2.963325","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","HTTP","334","GET /?id=12345 HTTP/1.1"
"26","2.963325","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","40","10000 > 49652 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=295 Win=65536 Len=0"
"29","3.130438","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","HTTP","556","HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/javascript)"
"30","3.130438","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","40","49652 > 10000 [ACK] Seq=295 Ack=517 Win=65024 Len=0"
"31","3.130438","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","40","10000 > 49652 [FIN, ACK] Seq=517 Ack=295 Win=65536 Len=0"
"32","3.130438","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","40","[TCP Dup ACK 30#1] 49652 > 10000 [ACK] Seq=295 Ack=517 Win=65024 Len=0"
"37","3.138443","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","40","49652 > 10000 [ACK] Seq=295 Ack=518 Win=65024 Len=0"
"38","3.138443","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","40","49652 > 10000 [FIN, ACK] Seq=295 Ack=518 Win=65024 Len=0"
"39","3.138443","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","40","10000 > 49652 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=296 Win=65536 Len=0"
```

Comment: silly question, but have you read the entire Wireshark manual?

Comment: i know why may happen DUP ACK, but in this case it seems no reasons for that